# PHP Script won't recognise email

Tags: php, html

I'm getting pretty far with my registration script now. This has been such an amazing learning curve for me. As of now I've just finished up some bugs with my user recognition and registration email send outs. I'm having some issues with recovering a password though. At the moment I am just trying to get an email recognised, here is my HTML and PHP:

HTML

```
<?php
    session_start();    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include "header.php" ?>
        <div id="wrapper">

             <form method="post" action="">
             <h2>Recover Password</h2>
             <div id="underline"></div>
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         <label for="usn">Email : </label>
                         <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="reset" />
                     </li>
                     <li class="buttons">
                         <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset Pass" class="xbutton" />
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </form>        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php include "prec.php" ?>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
if($_POST)
{

        if(empty($_POST['reset'])) 
        {
            echo 'Please enter all fields';
        }
        else
        {
            $email = $_POST['reset'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $db_name = 
            $db_user = 
            $db_pass = 

            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tweezy_php', 'tweezy_php', 'XXXXXX', 
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
            $stmt->execute(array($email));
            if($stmt->rowCount() === 1 )
            {
                echo "That email exists";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Sorry, that email doesn't exsist.";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

For some reason, no matter what I enter the supplied email is never recognised. Looking through my code I don't quite see why though. I've tried a couple of variations, but it just seems to give me the same result. I'm thinking it has something to do with my SQL query, but I can't seem to quite put my finger on it.

Any insights would be wonderful!

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: No error at all, my else statement just shows up.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, but ok...

Comment: You have two form inputs with the same name of 'reset'.

Comment: First thing, `session_start();` in **every** page used using sessions.

Comment: Yeah. Oh god so many answers fixing my issue, and damn I make stupid mistakes! @Fred my header.php which is included in every page already has that.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Ok. I didn't see it in your 2nd body of posted code, that's why I said that. Usually when it's not posted, I start asking questions (lol)

Comment: Haha no worries! I applaud you for bringing it up anyway, I'm quite sure in the future someone may not have it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input field is:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="reset" />
```

Change this to:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="email" />
```

And, in your PHP, you'd do something like this to retrieve the email from the user:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

A simple example to demonstrate why it's failing:

**test.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fieldname'])){
echo $_POST['fieldname']; //outputs "Submit" instead of the user input
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="fieldname"/>
<input type="submit" name="fieldname">

</form>
```

Both the input field and submit button has the same `name`. So when you input something and click on submit, you will find that instead of echoing the user input, it echoes the text `Submit`. This is because the first input is being overridden by the `name` attribute in your Submit button. This can be resolved by changing your `email` input's name attribute to something different, like `email` so it makes more sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. You explained all the points perfectly. I also want to thank everyone else again, you all really helped me out of this. I wish I could accept everyone's answer! :)

Comment: Just going to post a little comment here as it seems people don't think I actually understand the code you posted here, which I obviously do as you have just changed the names. When I was using `$_POST` it was getting confused as I had duplicate names (Silly mistake by myself). Thus, changing those names meant the correct variable will be targeted, resulting in my code being fixed. So, I find it quite offensive that people don't think I understand it, when the code was written by myself in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Change $email to This:

```
$email = $_POST['username'];
```

And

```
if(!isset($_POST['reset']))
```

Comment: There is no input named username

Comment: There was before the edit.

Comment: @ChrisLaarman Look to the comments of the other answer! The question was edited...

Comment: I see. Removed my downvote

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tweezy_php', 'tweezy_php', 'XXXXXX', 
    array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ));

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if(count($result) === 1 ){
    echo "That email exists";
}else{
    echo "Sorry, that email doesn't exsist.";
}
```

Also, you should change the `name` of the email's input. It is conflicting with another input and if two inputs have the same name without them being an array, the last input's value will be presented to the server.

That should resolve the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this. This fixed my issue, but after trying Chris's, Aynber and Amal's answer that also fixed my issue! Also having two of the same emails in my database didn't help much! I would accept this, but it is a little different from my current code and I want to be consistent. Thank you though, really big help.

Comment: No problem; as long as it works; that's what matters :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two fields in the form that contain `name="reset"`. One is the email field, the other is the submit button.

This will confuse things -- only one of those values will get into your `$_POST` array, and it looks like it's the wrong one.

You should tidy up the form and ensure that your field `name` attributes do not clash.

In addition, I note that the email field has a `label` near it that has `for="usn"`, but there isn't a `usn` field anywhere to be seen. That won't cause any problems, but is badly incorrect (it looks like a copy+paste bug) -- you probably fix that too.

Comment: Thanks for this. You are indeed correct, having two names for reset did cause issues with my code. Yes, that USN label was for a very early piece of code, thank you for showing me this! It shall be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you're checking the Reset button for a value and not the email field. Here's your email field:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
```

So you need to change this:

```
 if(empty($_POST['reset']))
```

AND

```
 $email = $_POST['reset'];
```

To check $_POST['username'] instead.

Comment: I actually just saw this when posting my question. I changed it to reset, still no luck though.

Comment: You don't want to use reset for the field name because that's the name of your button. Keep it as username, and change the variable in your PHP

Comment: Okay, I shall do this now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both your reset and email input fields are named reset (`name="reset"`). This will result in the first field (which should be named email) being overriden by your actual reset input field

Change your email input to

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="email" />
```

And your $email to

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: This fixed my issue, as well as so many more answers. You are all so helpful here, thank you once again.